# tooltip over jquery range slider handles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jquery rangeslider, and I'd like to have a tooltip that shows up over both handles. My code is below, and is adapted from http://jsfiddle.net/b6tux4we/   I just want one tooltip to appear at a time.

But for me, the tooltip over the first slider handles does not appear. The second one does, and works fine. Why? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

```
var tooltipmin_blobSpeed = $("<div style='font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid black;border-radius:4px; background-color:black; color:white; padding:3px' id='tooltip' />").css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -30,
    left: -5
}).hide();
var tooltipmax_blobSpeed = $("<div style='font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid black;border-radius:4px; background-color:black; color:white; padding:3px' id='tooltip' />").css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -30,
    left: -5
}).hide();  

var blobSpeedSlider = $( "#slider_blobSpeed" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    values: [ 1, 10 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        blobSpeedMinimum[currentblob] = ui.values[0]
        blobSpeedMaximum[currentblob] = ui.values[1]

        tooltipmin_blobSpeed.text(ui.values[0])
        tooltipmax_blobSpeed.text(ui.values[1])

    },
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        tooltipmin_blobSpeed.text(ui.values[0])
        tooltipmax_blobSpeed.text(ui.values[1])
    }       
})

$( "#slider_blobSpeed") 
    .find("ui-slider-handle")
    .first()
    .append(tooltipmin_blobSpeed)
    .hover(function() {
        tooltipmin_blobSpeed.show();
    }, function() {
        tooltipmin_blobSpeed.hide();
})

$( "#slider_blobSpeed") 
    .find(".ui-slider-handle")
    .last()
    .append(tooltipmax_blobSpeed)
    .hover(function() {
        tooltipmax_blobSpeed.show();
    }, function() {
        tooltipmax_blobSpeed.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, it is necessary to search for span instead of the class of span, otherwise, the tooltip HTML does not get inserted...

So, instead of

```
$( "#slider_blobSpeed") 
.find(".ui-slider-handle")
.last()
.append(tooltipmax_blobSpeed)
.hover(function() {
    tooltipmax_blobSpeed.show();
}, function() {
    tooltipmax_blobSpeed.hide();
});
```

Do this:

```
$( "#slider_blobSpeed") 
.find("span")
.first()
.append(tooltipmax_blobSpeed)
.hover(function() {
    tooltipmax_blobSpeed.show();
}, function() {
    tooltipmax_blobSpeed.hide(); 
});
```

and that results in a range slider with a tooltip that appears only as each span handle is hovered. Only one tooltip appears at a time, because you can only hover one span handle at a time.